# relative element out of viewport

Tags: html, css

Why my dropdown panel get out of the viewport
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uth7H.png

and how to fix that so it dose not get out of viewport and to be centred relative to the button when posiible

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHOo9.png

if possible only with CSS

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
        <button class="button-std dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon-home"></span>
            <span> Dropdown Button</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-positionner">
            <div class="dropdown-std">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Another Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS

```
    .dropdown-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-positionner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
.dropdown-std {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    left: -50%;
}
.dropdown-container:hover .dropdown-std {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you have  negative left positions)

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-positionner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
.dropdown-std {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    left: -50%;
}
.dropdown-container:hover .dropdown-std {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-positionner-edge {
    left: 0;
}

.dropdown-positionner-edge .dropdown-std {
    left: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <button class="button-std dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon-home"></span>
    <span> Dropdown Button</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-positionner dropdown-positionner-edge">
    <div class="dropdown-std">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Another Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown-container">
  <button class="button-std dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon-home"></span>
    <span> Dropdown Button</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-positionner">
    <div class="dropdown-std">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Another Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/vkL4s5Lz/4/)**

Comment: Question edited plz take a look
i need it to be centred when possible

Comment: You have to use 2 classes, one when is on the edges and another when is on the center

Comment: and how to do that ? I am noob in web dev :p Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your css is moving it's contents, here is working fiddle and css contents:

```
    .dropdown-container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .dropdown-positionner {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdown-std {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        left: 0%;
    }
    .dropdown-container:hover .dropdown-std {
        display: block;
    }
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/j1kvfzzf/

Comment: I know that but I want it to be centred relative to the button when possible

Comment: I added breaks in the html so that the links stack, does this do the trick? https://fiddle.jshell.net/j1kvfzzf/1/    if you require it to be in CSS there is a way to achieve that as well, let me know.

Comment: I understand what your looking to do, there may be a way with css only but I don't know how, I could create a javascript/jquery solution that would do the trick, let me know if that would be helpful and if so I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I already know how to do that in js but I want to gain some performance thats why I need it only in CSS